# Eine Liste aus / eine Liste von – Wahl der Präposition

Tags: word-choice, preposition

Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen *eine Liste aus* und *eine Liste von*?

Wann sagt man:

> Eine Liste *aus* Objekten, Menschen, Zahlen, Typen, …
>
> Eine Liste *von* Objekten, Menschen, Zahlen, Typen, …

Comment: I think the first one misses a verb. I would use "aus" with the verb "bestehen (aus)". So: "Eine Liste bestehend aus Objekten...". But I am not sure with that.

Comment: Ich würde eher auf beides verzichten: "Eine Liste Objekte, Menschen, Zahlen..."

Answer (score 4):

**Aus** literally means **made of/from** in this case, while **von** usually means the same as **of**.

> Ein Zaun aus Holz.

*A fence made of wood.*

> Ein Zaun aus Latten.

*A fence made from latches.*

BUT

> Ein Zaun von vielen.

*One fence of many.*

> Eine Liste von Zutaten.

*A list of ingredients.*

When it is clear the list isn't meant as a physical object, making a list **aus** instead of **von** means you focus on the list rather than the things on it. But this is **very** subtle.

> Er hatte eine Liste aus Zutaten und Arbeitsschritten.

*He had a list made of ingredients and work steps.*

> Er hatte eine Liste von Zutaten und Arbeitsschritten.

*He had a list of ingredients and work steps.*

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility would be a Genitive construct, that is, we use "der", "derjenigen", "solcher", "dieser" and so on:

> Liste der Primzahlen
>
> die Liste derjenigen Primzahlen, die zwischen 100 und 1000 liegen
>
> Die Liste seiner Vergehen ist lang.

Answer (score 1):

No difference to me. "Liste aus..." implies "Liste bestehend aus...". All three sound equally fine to me.

"Liste Objekte..." without anything should also be grammatically correct but to me sounds less colloquial or common. I am not sure how or if this construct can be used if you have different things in the list, as in: "Liste Objekte und Menschen", to me does sound really strange and perhaps wrong.

For my ear in the first three options, the emphasis is on it being a "list", while in the last option the emphasis shifts a bit to the objects that make up the list.

Another option similar to "Liste Objekte..." could be with compound nouns, e.g.: Zahlenliste.

Comment: I disagree. *Liste aus* would define what the list is made of, not what the list contains.

Comment: Not sure I understand which part of my answer you refer to. Also for lists I don't see any difference between "contains" and "made of".

Comment: To the first line: *No difference to me. "Liste aus..." implies "Liste bestehend aus...".* I can have a list that is made of paper (because I wrote it onto a piece of paper) that contains names. So it is a *Liste aus Papier*, but a *Liste von Namen*.

Comment: I see, and agree that if the list is made of paper I would use "aus". Similarly if you gave me a list it would be a: "Liste **von** Thorsten". However I understood the original question to refer specifically to the items that are listed. And I still think that "aus" and "von" can both be used in that case.